# Deleted Partitions while installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I am new to linux, as a windows user i thought installing Ubuntu on my old windows laptop will be as similar as installing windows later after installing Ubuntu, I realised that I accidentally deleted my partitions and data from my computer. I tried using testdisk but later i gave up because i don't want to mess up with the lost data. I have no idea about what should be done next.

Comment: Data recovery is a very slow & laborious process...  It can take weeks & longer, thus restoration of your data from backups is the easy fix.  FYI:  None of this differs in Ubuntu to any other OS.. Backups are the same back in 1970s with tape as today with external drives; we just use faster media and the OS involved doesn't really matter - it's the same for all OSes.

Comment: Ok, but what can we do to recover that data?

Comment: Restore from backup is the best way to recovery. Most that use Windows say Windows tools work better for NTFS, but many of the better programs are paid for. You can try testdisk or photorec, but parts of your data are gone since you overwrote it with Ubuntu. And if using Ubuntu you are overwriting more of it as it is used. Only use another system to look at disk or live installer or Windows repair/recovery disk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Read the duplicate link; there are multiple references & details on using `testdisk` , `photorec` etc...   or you can take it to a recovery centre who will charge for it, as yes its a detailed & somewhat complex process (*that is very slow*)...  Recovery from backups the easy solution.  Possibly best is to *clone* the drive & recover from the *cloned* copy so you can start again if you make a mistake etc...